# LiveRebel Update Strategy

Tags: deployment, tomcat7, jrebel

I am trying to utilize LiveRebel on my production environment. After most parts are configured I tried to perform update on my application from lets say version `1.1` to `1.3` as shown below

[image]

Does this mean that LiveRebel require two server installation on 2 physical IP addresses ? Can I have two server on 2 virtual IP addresses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rolling restarts use request routing to achieve zero downtime for the users. Sessions are first drained by waiting for old sessions to expire and routing new ones to an identical application on another server. When all sessions are drained, application is updated, while the other server handles the requests.

So, as you can see, for zero downtime you need additional server to handle the requests while application is updated. Full restart doesn't have that requirement, but results in downtime for users.

As for the question about IPs, as long as the two server (virtual) machines can see each other , doesn't really make much difference.